# How do I pass a property of my razor model to a partial?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page, where the SomeList property of my page model is of type `List<Blah>`, with the following:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_QueueTable", Model.SomeList)
```

I have a partial with the following:

```
@page
@model List<Blah>
```

When I hit my breakpoint, trying to access Model gives me a NullReferenceException.

If I inspect ViewData inside the Non-Public members of the ViewBag I see the Model I'm looking for.

How do I set this up properly so that I can simply reference Model in my partial so I can act on my list?

Comment: I have not had to do this in .net core, but i am wondering if it has to do with the fact that it is async. What happens if you use the regular .Partial instead of async?

Comment: I tried that, but got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I had an @page directive at the top of my partial

I tried to remove the directive when I created the partial, but VS gave me an error saying that it must be present.

I didn't give it another thought, until a co-worker finally pointed it out. I removed the directive, did a clean, did a build and I'm in business.

Comment: I was about to recommend the same thing